# Rename Folders, Sub-folders and files

Tags: python

If a path is long inside the specified folder, then I want to rename those folders and files. I could do it for files but was not able to do it for folders.

First, need to rename files and still if the path is long then need to rename it for folders as well. To rename files I have written the below code and it is working for all the files in all folders.

```
Source_Path = '/Users/name/Downloads/Test'
for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in os.walk(Source_Path):
    for file_name in filenames:
        path = os.path.join(dirpath, file_name)
        new_path = path.split('/', 5)[-1]
        if len(new_path) > 40:
            file_name_input = input('New file name: ')
            New_Name = file_name_input + (re.findall('\..*', file_name))[0]
            new_path = os.rename(os.path.join(dirpath, file_name), os.path.join(dirpath, New_Name))
```

To rename folders, I tried the below code but it shows an error when a subfolder needs to be renamed.

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

This code is just renaming last folder with the above error. How can I rename all the folders?

```
for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in os.walk(Source_Path):
    for file_name in filenames:
        path = os.path.join(dirpath, file_name)
        if len(path) > 40:
            folder_name_input = input('New Folder Name: ')
            new_folder_name = dirpath.rsplit('/', 1)[0] + '/' + folder_name_input
            new_path = os.rename(dirpath, new_folder_name)
```

There can be N number of folders and N number of files with different extensions, which I want to reduce to some specific length of 200 characters. I have used 40 just for example. Example of a folder structure:

eg.

```
/Users/name/Downloads/Test/Level1Subfolder1/nameofthefile1.pdf
/Users/name/Downloads/Test/Level1Subfolder1/Level2Subfolder2/nameofthefile2.pdf
/Users/name/Downloads/Test/Level1Subfolder1/Level2Subfolder2/Level3Subfolder3/nameofthefile3.pdf
```

to the folder structure like below:

```
/Users/name/Downloads/Test/inputname1/inputfilename1.pdf
/Users/name/Downloads/Test/inputname1/inputname2/inputfilename2.pdf
/Users/name/Downloads/Test/inputname1/inputname2/inputname3/inputfilename3.pdf
```

Comment: Your idea is to pass the new names for the folders via input? In that case you are missing a check for the folders that you already renamed.

Comment: Right. But I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: You can create a dictionary mapping old names to new names. So before remaming you can check if the old name is in the dict then use the new name otherwise input the new name and add to dict

Comment: Thanks @FrancoPiccolo. I will try that. Is there any way to rename folders and sub-folders?

Comment: os.rename should work